# CSS3 Animation within Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, css, animation, fullpage.js

I'm trying to get a CSS3 'animate on scroll transition/animation to work within some containers using fullpage.js.

**Animate on scroll:** http://www.cssscript.com/demo/animate-elements-scroll-aos/

**Fullpage.js:** http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

I can get the animation working on it's own but when with the fullpage.js, adding 'data-aos="fade-up' to determine what to animate leaves the space for the image the transition is applied to but no image is displayed; so for all I know the transition could still be happening but having it in this instance means I can't see what's being animated lol.

**Looking at the code below could anybody tell if there is something immediately obvious?**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script src="js/aos.js"></script>
<script>
AOS.init({
easing: 'ease-in-out-sine'
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage'],
            sectionsColor: [],
            scrollOverflow: true
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section " data-color="black">
<img  class="shadow" width="50%" src="work/del-1.jpg" alt="Deloitte"  data-
aos="fade-up"></img>
</div>
<div class="section" data-color="green">
<h2>Green panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="section" data-color="blue"><h2>Blue panel</h2></div>
<div class="section" data-color="grey"><img  class="shadow" width="70%" 
src="work/aus-cc1.jpg" alt="Deloitte"></img></div>
<div class="section" data-color="grey"><img  class="shadow" width="70%" 
src="work/aus-cc2.jpg" alt="Deloitte"></img></div>
<div class="section" data-color="grey"><img  class="shadow" width="70%" 
src="work/aus-help1.jpg" alt="Deloitte"></img></div>
<div class="section" data-color="grey"><img  class="shadow" width="70%" 
src="work/aus-help2.jpg" alt="Deloitte"></img></div>
<div class="section" data-color="yellow">
<h2>Yellow panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="section" data-color="orange">
<h2>Orange panel</h2>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the option `scrollBar:true` so you can keep the auto scrolling behaviour but keep the scroll bar visible. Check the [example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html).

This way the page will still fire the `scroll` event.

In any case, I would encourage you to make use of fullPage.js callbacks to add or remove classes, that's the better way of doing it.

Also, check [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M&t=27s) that uses the state classes added by fullpage.js to create css3 animations.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to bypass this, is to use the `fp-normal-scroll` class on that specific section that has the lazy-load-like plugin you've specified. *However, this is not publicly released and might cause some issues (but I, myself haven't ran into one yet).*

This is how you will be able to scroll and see what animates and what not.

Then, you will need to add the `hybrid: true` option to your init as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage'],
        sectionsColor: [],
        scrollOverflow: true,
        hybrid: true
    });
});
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1191/)** for this method.

Comment: `hybrid` is not a supported option by fullpage.js. It is not in the docs and it is an experimental option in development that contain bugs. Therefore, there's no official demo either :)

Comment: Hey @Alvaro , I clearly stated that in my second sentence :)

Comment: Yeah, just saying there's no such thing as an official demo :)

Comment: Removed the term official earlier. Now it is just *a demo*.